# Replacing files in drawable folder on android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, drawable

I am making an app in Eclipse, but I've got some problems changing an image in the app. I have an .xml file that should show two buttons in my app. The code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_button_pressed" android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_button_pressed" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_button_normal" android:state_enabled="true"/>
```

Now I want to replace one of the images, because it had the wrong scale. So I replaced the `background_button_pressed` with the new image in the right scale. But it still shows the old one, when I run the app on both the emulator and on a phone. Why?

I have tried the following:

- cleaned project
- made a new image called "background_button_pressed2" and changed the xml accordingly
- i have deleted the bin folder entirely to make sure it didn't load an old compiler
- restarted Eclipse
- cleaned/build several times
- tried with another img file in the drawable to make sure it wasn't the code (same result)
- checked every drawable folders to make sure it isn't located several places and loads one of them

  I am new to Eclipse and this just doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: you don't have a state for 
android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"
i suggest you to check your states again and remove the unnecessary states. and try with different drawables also.

Comment: Use a 9patch if you are not using one already.

Comment: Did you mean to put `state_pressed` in your second line instead of `state_focused`? That would explain why you aren't seeing it change when you press it. There is no drawable assigned for when you press the button while it's enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_button_pressed" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_button_normal"/>
```

If you want to change the drawable state for setEnable(false) then you need the following code

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/background_button_disabled"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/background_button_normal" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/background_button_pressed" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/background_button_normal"/>
```